# jsp form send data to servlet without changing page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I use jsp+servlets and have a form. How can I send the form data to a servlet (to the doPost() method) without leaving the actual page, that contains the form?

I want to press the button "submit", the data should be sent and I want to still remain on the page with the form. I would rather not use javascript.

I have on `http://localhost/myproject/`

```
<form action="http://localhost/myproject/anotherpage" method="POST">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">
<br />
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

when clicking the submit button i get forwarded to the following page: `http://localhost/myproject/anotherpage`

but I want to stay on

```
http://localhost/myproject/
```

edit: right now I am going to write

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

in the doPost() method

Comment: But how are you leaving the page by making a POST request?

Comment: try using ajax.  e.g. jquery.ajax

Answer (score 6):

You should have a form with **method="POST"** in your **JSP**

```
    <form method="post">
        <input type="number" name="number1" id="number1" />
        +
        <input type="number" name="number2" id="number2" />

        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

Then in your **servlets**, in the **doPost** method, you have to get the parameters of your form with **getParameter("name")**, do what you want on it, then resend it to your JSP (**setAttribute**).
Don't forget to **link** with your jsp (last line of my example)

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String textNumber1 = request.getParameter("number1");
        String textNumber2 = request.getParameter("number2");
        int number1 = (!textNumber1.isEmpty() ? Integer.parseInt(textNumber1) : 0);
        int number2 = (!textNumber2.isEmpty() ? Integer.parseInt(textNumber2) : 0);
        int result = number1 + number2;

        request.setAttribute("result", Integer.toString(result));

        request.setAttribute("number1", Integer.toString(number1));
        request.setAttribute("number2", Integer.toString(number2));

        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/calc.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

Finally on your **JSP**, get the attribute from your servlet you want to display on the same page with **getAttribute**

```
<%
    String number1 = (String) request.getAttribute("number1");
    String number2 = (String) request.getAttribute("number2");
    String result  = (String) request.getAttribute("result");

    if (number1 != null && number2 != null && result != null) {
        out.print(String.format("<p>Result of %s + %s = <strong>%s</strong></p>", number1, number2, result));
    }
%>
```

This example is a little calculator that show you the result of number1 + number 2 on the same page of the form ;)

Answer (score 5):

I would advise you not to forward to initial page from the second one, but instead to redirect to it in order to follow the [Post-Redirect-Get pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

If you do not, the user will see in his URL bar the address of the page where he posted data, and if he clicks the back button he will get the ugly message of duplicate post submissions.

So in you `doPost()` method just to :

```
response.sendRedirect("/back/to/your/page");
```

As as alternative, you could *hide* the JSP page behind the servlet, and have the servlet to directly forward to the JSP page for a GET request, and *do its work* for a POST and then either forward to the JSP or redirect to itself. In that case, you would not set any action in the `<form>` tag to have the data posted to same URL.

As it would keep same URL, you could eventually simply do a forward, but I still recommend a redirect to avoid the back button problem.

Answer (score 4):

On you servlet, define the jsp you want to return.

```
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/path/to/your/jsp");
    requestDispatcher.forward(req, res);
```

If you mean to send data without refreshing current page, you might want to look at sending ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't let you stay on the form page, but redirects you back to it right away. And you can of course use the values you just entered.

JSP form

```
<form method="post" action="yourServlet">
```

Servlet (in `doPost()`)

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/back/to/your.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascript and ajax (XMLHttpRequest), or specify a target to your form, that references a hidden iframe.